# Why does the graph in excel change after typing in dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Image before typing in all the dates:

[image]

Image after typing in all the dates

[image]

I think I have a trouble producing a solid graph with all the dates in it. After I change the name of the last date from "December" to "18 Dec," the graph becomes distorted. If anyone knows how to solve this question, I would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both seem to be line charts and not scatter charts.

**General rule:** In line charts, the order of data is kept in the chart (from left to right), even if the X-axis includes numbers that are not in ascending order. **Exception:** If X-axis only includes dates, then points are plotted (from left to right) in ascending order of dates.

**First chart**

December is not a date. Therefore, the general rule is kept.

**Second chart**

All X-axis data are dates. Therefore, the exception applies.

Excel interprets 17 and 18 not as years but a the days of the month that follows.

Furthermore, all dates are assumed to belong to the current year.

Because of the previous two sentences, the points are displayed (from left to right) in the following order: 17.Jan, 18.Jan, 17.Feb, 18.Feb,...

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! It helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It may be because december in the first pic is not a date and it is in the second one, which makes the whole column have a date value